# Spectral energy density and energy content per normal mode

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, spectroscopy

How can I see that a spectral energy density given by a cubic law
$$
\rho(\omega)=\frac{\hbar}{2\pi^2c^3} \omega^3
$$
has the property that the average energy content per normal mode is
$$
\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}=\frac{1}{2}\hbar \omega_{\alpha}?
$$
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Something doesn't make sense in what you've written. In the first $\omega$ is a variable frequency that can take on any value (except, likely up to some cut-off frequency).  But in the second, the frequency is a *particular* $\omega$. Can you clarify? What kind of system are you treating? What is the dispersion relation? What assumption are you making about the relationship between the energy and frequency, etc.?

Comment: I am reading some books and articles about Stochastics Electrodynamics. This theory assumes that there is a random electromagnetic classical radiation in the empty space. Assuming that the spectral energy density of the radiation is Lorentz-invariant they derive that the spectral energy density is the one I wrote, then the authors comment that this density has the property that the average energy content per normal mode of the radiation is given by the second equation. I did not find any justification of this, how can I verify it?